# String literal corrupt in IntelliJ BUG?

Tags: intellij-idea, file-encodings

I don't understand, what I happening. I have a string, which contains non-breakable characters 160. When I trace function call with this string passed, I see passed string corrupted.

Screenshot before function entrance

[image]

You see contant `"    English "` which is passing to function `getChild`.

Then I press `F7` to enter the function and see[image]

Characted `160` is prefixed with `B`.

What a hell???

**UPDATE**

Problem has self-cured after I re-edited the live. Although I did copy pasting, it helped, i.e. I never re-type string myself.

**UPDATE 2 -- RESURRECTS**

Error resurrects. Just cutting and pasting `"    English "` back does not help. But more complex editing, introducing temporary variable and then inline it -- helps.

Looks like it is either encoding problem or editor bug, related with char 160.

**UPDATE 3**

Now it returns in 100% explicit manner:

[image]

i.e. `tmp` variable is assigned and immediately receives incorrect value.

Comment: When you expand, do you see `66` for the `B`s or something else? -- ah, it self cured... well too bad :)

Comment: I saw both Bs and 160s.